# Obfuscating URLs in WordPress

Tags: obfuscation

Hi I have a membership site and as part of the membership users can download some reports, which are all stored in a particular folder on the server. Is there a way to obfuscate the URLs of these reports so a user would not be able to automate the downloading of all reports?

Answer (score 0):

Hash the user's username and include that in the filename of the report that he is downloading.

Comment: I was just answering in general. I am afraid I am not sure how you would do this specifically in WordPress, without adding your own PHP code.